# What to do with error 'Please review the problems below:' using cocoon gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, cocoon-gem

I am creating an ruby on rails 5 application. It is a todolist kind of application and using simple_form, haml-rails and cocoon gem. This is a application with nested form.

1. Generated a scaffold for goal and created model for action
   Goal.rb and Action.rb

   > ```
   > class Goal < ApplicationRecord
   >   has_many :actions
   >   accepts_nested_attributes_for :actions, reject_if: :all_blank
   > end
   >
   > class Action < ApplicationRecord
   >   belongs_to :goal
   > end
   > ```

   2. Then added the actions_attribute to permit in the params

> ```
> class GoalsController < ApplicationController   before_action :set_goal, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]   def index
>     @goals = Goal.all   end   def show   end   def new
>     @goal = Goal.new   end   def edit   end   def create
>     @goal = Goal.new(goal_params)
>     respond_to do |format|
>       if @goal.save
>         format.html { redirect_to @goal, notice: 'Goal was successfully created.' }
>         format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @goal }
>       else
>         format.html { render :new }
>         format.json { render json: @goal.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
>       end
>     end   end   def update
>     respond_to do |format|
>       if @goal.update(goal_params)
>         format.html { redirect_to @goal, notice: 'Goal was successfully updated.' }
>         format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @goal }
>       else
>         format.html { render :edit }
>         format.json { render json: @goal.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
>       end
>     end   end   def destroy
>     @goal.destroy
>     respond_to do |format|
>       format.html { redirect_to goals_url, notice: 'Goal was successfully destroyed.' }
>       format.json { head :no_content }
>     end   end   private
>     def set_goal
>       @goal = Goal.find(params[:id])
>     end
>     def goal_params
>       params.require(:goal).permit(:name, :purpose, :deadline, actions_attributes: [:step])
>     end
> ```
>
> end

3. Forms for both form.html and action.html

**_form.html.haml**

> ```
> = simple_form_for(@goal) do |f|
>   = f.error_notification
>
>   .form-inputs
>     = f.input :name
>     = f.input :purpose
>     = f.input :deadline
>     %h3 Actions
>     #tasks
>       = f.simple_fields_for :actions do |action|
>         = render 'action_fields', f: action
>       .links
>         = link_to_add_association 'Add', f, :actions
>
>   .form-actions
>     = f.button :submit
> ```
>
> // action.html.haml
>       .nested-fields
>         = f.input :step
>         = f.input :done, as: :boolean
>         = link_to_remove_association "remove task", f

log in the console when i submit form

```
Processing by GoalsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"jel0g+oCkNaspe7T9dz7suDczIOdoKJqPqPDK9ta0WLPbwaSPBwshrDD2BrNAFeLoDx+0/soe11MWaZaH8cQoA==", "goal"=>{"name"=>"ja", "purpose"=>"asdfd", "deadline"=>"asdfasd", "actions_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"step"=>"ARasd", "done"=>"1", "_destroy"=>"false"}, "1475080334356"=>{"step"=>"", "done"=>"0", "_destroy"=>"false"}}}, "commit"=>"Create Goal"}
Unpermitted parameter: _destroy
Unpermitted parameter: _destroy
   (0.5ms)  BEGIN
   (0.5ms)  ROLLBACK
  Rendering goals/new.html.haml within layouts/application
  Rendered goals/_action_fields.html.haml (18.5ms)
  Rendered goals/_action_fields.html.haml (26.5ms)
  Rendered goals/_action_fields.html.haml (19.0ms)
  Rendered goals/_form.html.haml (252.5ms)
  Rendered goals/new.html.haml within layouts/application (309.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 932ms (Views: 898.5ms | ActiveRecord: 1.0ms)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The console log shows: `Unpermitted parameter: done`

This is because in your controller, only these parameters are permitted:

```
params.require(:goal).permit(:name, :purpose, :deadline, actions_attributes: [:step])
```

Comment: I also added :done inside the paramater now  but another problem occur updated in my question

Comment: You will have to add at least `:id` and  `:_destroy`. Please check [documentation](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon#strong-parameters-gotcha)